# Can I use Beetel 450TC1 as wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, modem

Recently I have opted for broadband connection which is coming directly cat5 cable with RJ45 port to my laptop. They have provided me with IP address, default Gateway, subnet mask, preferred DNS and alternate DNS server information. Also the username and password.

The Modem model is Beetel 450TC1 which is actually an ADSL+2 Router. The modem has 4 lan port and one RJ11 port (for internet).

Can I use this modem as a wireless hotspot without connecting the RJ45 cable directly to my laptop?

If yes, can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You'll have to reset the router and deactivate the internet and put it into bridge mode.

After that in the LAN settings select relay as primary function and give you DHCP server the IP of your ISP (your DNS server IP) in the slot below where you select relay option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from what I have found, that model is wireless capable. Looks like you just need to activate it within the settings of the router.

This is pretty localized question and you may find better help by calling you service provider, but here is some information which may help you configure your router.

[Configuration of Beetel 450 TC1 WiFi ADSL Modem for BSNL, MTNL and Airtel Broadband](http://www.techlineinfo.com/configuration-of-beetel-450-tc1-wifi-adsl-modem-for-bsnl-mtnl-and-airtel-broadband/)

[Set up beetel 450TC1 router for BSNL broadband](http://pradeepnayak.in/tutorials/2012/07/09/set-up-beetel-450tc1-modem-for-bsnl-broadband/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I am asking is that "Is it possible to make the ADSL+2 modem router as wireless router when the internet is coming as the RJ45 in the modem".

Comment: What you are saying does not make sense. The modem is a router. Both of the instructions I linked to have instructions how to setup the wireless function of the modem/router. Please call your provider if you don't understand this.

Comment: Ok. Let me rephrase my question. Is it possible to use a DSL modem as a Switch where the internet source is coming from the cat5 cable with RJ45 and then share that internet wirelessly. I cant use the RJ11 port as my internet source in my DSL modem as the ISP does not provide me one.

Comment: This is still very confusing. The way your question reads is the Beetel modem is provided with the service. Are you saying your ISP provides a cat5 cable for Internet with no equipment?  In that case, no, you can not use the DSL modem to make the internet connection wireless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can actually use your RJ45 cable coming from your ISP as an input to the ADSL+WIFI beetel router and can use the same to route the internet. All you have to do is got to your router settings page, 192.168.1.1 and username: admin and password: admin . Go to Interface setup -> LAN . Check the DHCP option and you can see thre options like Enabled , Disabled, Relay. Click on relay and it asks for DHCP address, give it as googles 8.8.8.8 even though its DNS server. Now your LAN ports act as Input ports :). Anyways after that restart your modem,mine is working :)