# Can I use Beetel 450TC3 as wireless router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I am trying to extend wireless internet connectivity to another part of my house. 
My current modem + wireless router does not cover my entire house. So, I have installed a cat5 cable with RJ45 port leading to that part of the house. Now I want a wireless internet there.

However, I have a Beetel 450TC3 ADSL+2 Router/ modem, which I want to use as a wireless router. It has 4 LAN ports and one RJ11 port. All the LAN ports act as internet output, RJ11 port is for DSL input.

Can I use this the 450TC3 as a wireless hotspot/ router? i.e. Is it possible to reconfigure one of the LAN ports to act as input through my CAT5 cable, and then broadcast wireless internet?

If yes, can anybody help me with that? (I have seen this post, but it didn't work for me: [Can I use Beetel 450TC1 as wireless router?](https://superuser.com/questions/564283/can-i-use-beetel-450tc1-as-wireless-router) )

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that question. The two modems are different, and therefore possibly have a different way to make them work as a router.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect a LAN port on the first router to a LAN port on the second router with a crossover cable, it should put both switches in the routers on the same network and accomplish exactly what you want.  It may work with a regular straight-through cable, too, so try that before you crimp/buy a new crossover cable.

Just make sure you disable DHCP on the second router or else you are likely to get addressing conflicts.  Disabling other router functionalities would be a good idea as well.